# First order system of equations in DE

Tags: laplace-transform

Looking to solve the following system of equations

$$x'_1=4x_1-x_2$$
$$x'_2=-4x_1+4x_2$$

$$x_1(0)=3, x_2(0)=2$$

I need to solve this equation using Laplace and then I can use the coefficients and use Cramer's rule to solve for $x_1$ and then plug back into $x_2$ to solve for that variable  .

The answer is

$x_1=2e^{2t}+e^{6t}$

$x_2=4e^{2t}-2e^{6t}$

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to add them one second I'll edit my post

Comment: The t in x1 and x2 is supposed to be in the exponent

Comment: I looked at that example already couldn't quite understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given:

$$x'_1=4x_1-x_2, ~x_1(0) = 3 \\ x'_2=-4x_1+4x_2, ~x_2(0)=2$$

Following this [*link*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsLaplace.aspx) (there are many other approaches), we take the Laplace of each equation and get:

$$s x_1(s) - x_1(0) = 4 x_1(s) - x_2(s) \\ s x_2(s) - x_2(0) = - 4x_1(s) + 4 x_2(s)$$

We substitute the initial conditions and now have:

$$s x_1(s) - 3 = 4 x_1(s) - x_2(s) \\ s x_2(s) - 2 = - 4 x_1(s) + 4 x_2(s)$$

Rearranging like terms, we get:

$$(s - 4)~x_1(s) + x_2(s) = 3 \\ 4~ x_1(s) + (s-4)~ x_2(s) = 2$$

Can you now proceed as you described with Cramer's rule to find $x_1(s)$ and $x_2(s)$ and then find the Inverse Laplace transforms for $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$?

Using [*Cramer's Rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) (and many other ways) and then the [*Inverse Laplace Transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform), you should end up with:

$$x_1(s) = \dfrac{3 s-14}{s^2 - 8 s + 12} \implies x_1(t) = 2 e^{2t} + e^{6t}$$

$$x_2(s) = \dfrac{2 s- 20}{s^2 - 8 s + 12} \implies x_2(t) = 4e^{2t}-2e^{6t}$$

If you need an example, see this [*link*](http://inside.mines.edu/~jjechura/ProcessDynamics/05_CramersRule.pdf), under the heading "Solution of Systems of Initial Value ODEs".

**Update 1**

Our system can be written as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
(s-4) & 1\\4 & (s-4) \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(s)\\x_2(s) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
3\\2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Using Cramer's Rule, for $x_1(s)$, we would have:

$$x_1(s) = \dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}
3&1\\
2 & (s-4) \\
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
(s-4) &1\\
4 &(s-4) 
\end{vmatrix}} = \dfrac{3(s-4)-2}{(s-4)^2-4} = \dfrac{3s-14}{s^2-8s+12}$$

It is worth noting that you can totally avoid using Cramer's Rule here and just find the inverse of the system's matrix directly to solve for $x_1(s)$ and $x_2(s)$ and then do the Inverse Laplace Transform. You should try this after you get this approach. There are many other approaches to solve these types of  problems (eigenvalues/eigenvectors, matrix exponential, fundamental matrix ...).

**Update 2:**

Using Cramer's Rule, for $x_2(s)$, we would have:

$$x_2(s) = \dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}
(s-4)&3\\
4 & 2 \\
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
(s-4) &1\\
4 &(s-4) 
\end{vmatrix}} = \dfrac{2(s-4)-12}{(s-4)^2-2} = \dfrac{2s-20}{s^2-8s+12}$$

Comment: Where did the -4 go in the right side of equation 2 and how did you take the laplace of both sides to get those two equations

Comment: If I have $s x_1 (s) = 4 x_1(s)$, I can write that as $(s - 4)x_1(s) = 0$. Clear? Rearranging common things on one side (moved the 4 term to the LHS).

Comment: Okay so how do I go about putting that ino cramers

Comment: I didn't realize x' was like solving a normal second order equation

Comment: How do you go about setting up that matrix divided by another matrix then to find the determinant of both and divide them   I don't understand the positions in the matrix and how they relate back to the two equations we solved for

Comment: I am trying to but doesn't seem to plug in rigjt for my two matrix

Comment: Nvm had a typo in my notes

Comment: Solved my problem

Comment: Excellent to hear - I would try a few more examples, just to be efficient and make sure you have it down. Then, try a 3x3 example like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068473/how-to-solve-a-linear-system-in-matrix-form-using-laplace-transform.

Comment: Nvm disn't solve it

Comment: I am getting 3s-20 for the denominator of x1

Comment: Think I finally got it

Comment: Thanks for your patience lol

Comment: Sure that would be great

Comment: Awesome thanks for the update  so will I be able to usually sub back in x1 to the first equation ti solve for x2  doING a second cramers I would try and avoid if.I could

Comment: Could you make a edit and just show the matrix for x2?

Comment: The Cramer matrix