# Initial value problem , system of equations involved , solve using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

Can anyone help me solve this problem, I could not find a similar solution on the web.

Solve the following problem :
Initial value problem, 
System of equations involved , 
Using Laplace transform

$$ \vec{x}=\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  4&1\\
  -4&6
\end{array}
\right] $$

$$\vec{x}(0)= \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1\\
  -2
\end{array}
\right] $$
Thanks in advance

Comment: like `$\vec{x}$`

Comment: did you try to convert it to a system of equations?

Comment: I do not know how to do that

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068473 please

Comment: Shouldn't it be of form $x'=Ax+b$?

Comment: This is how I got it on the exam